# Is 'foreach' still bad in 'modern' unity ( >= 5.4.x)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Historically, one of the taboo constructs in Unity3D was the use of c# **foreach** block because each iteration of the loop would consume a few bytes of data uncessarily.

Curious if that's still the case on modern releases?

My Googling and (very rudimentary) testing is coming up with non-conclusive results and I'd like to leach off of someone else's knowledge here rather than dive into low-level benchmarking myself.  :-)

Has anyone poked at this recently to determine if it's still necessary to avoid **foreach** in Unity3D?

Comment: This reminds me of one of my favorite quotes: (Cunningham's Law) "The best way to get the right answer on the Internet is not to ask a question, it's to post the wrong answer." ;-)

Comment: @tass True... ok I'm going to go ahead and say that it's perfectly fine to use foreach now.  Bring it, internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, `foreach` is no longer bad in 'modern' unity but the fix is not yet fully released.

It was first fixed on a **special** build *Unity Patch 5.3.5p8* on early July, which you can get from [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-c-compiler-on-5-3-5p8.417363/#n21). This is a special Edition you must get to receive that fix.

Now, Unity upgraded their compiler to *Mono 4.4* on [Unity 5.5 beta](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/unity5.5.0b10) release which is not yet final release. It fixed the `foreach` problem. Once this version is released in the coming months, `foreach` memory allocation will be a thing of the past. You can still [download](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) for testing purposes but don't release a game with a beta build.

> Scripting: Upgrade C# compiler to Mono 4.4. The new compiler still
>   targets C# 4 and .Net 3.5, but provides better performance and many
>   bug fixes.

It is now fixed but the fix is still in beta mode.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick - you might consider rewording the first bit to "No, it is no longer a problem, but [...]" or "Yes, but it won't be once the next version is fully released" since otherwise it looks a bit like the Q/A pair is "Is 'foreach' still bad in 'modern' unity? Yes." - which doesn't seem to be the spirit of your answer, based on your last sentence where you reiterate your answer of "yes".

Comment: Appreciate the info.  I'll sadly shake my head and keep writing those silly 'for int i; i < count...' loops just a bit longer.

Comment: Yup. You just have to do that for few more months until 5.5 release but you can sleep well knowing that there is now a fix in a future release.

Comment: Update Unity 5.6
jackson dunstan did some benchmark on the foreach problem:
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3805